# Twitter search with name and location

Tags: twitter

I am trying twitter search using name and location. However, adding the location parameter to the Http web request url is giving me a 401 unauthorized exception.

My web request Url that works:
"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=John%20Doe"

The one that doesn't:
"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=John%20Doe&near=seattle&within=20&unis=mi"

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kushal.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://twitter.com/search-advanced) might help you. Go and fill the form & finally hit `Search`.

[image]

Also, take a look at this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search) to call with `location` etc..